# New with MS Flow. Just can't get it to work

Tags: flow

I need a very simple flow that sends a recurring e-mail at a given interval. Say I want to generate a ticket every third month for some recurring task.

I am testing right now that it sends an e-mail every 5 minutes to see if it works.

I created a flow with the trigger on recurrence - schedule. Gave my UTC+1 timezone. Gave a start time (say 5 minutes from now).

Then I added an action `Send an email (Office 365 Outlook)`, specified the e-mail to out ticketing system in "To", wrote testing in subject and body and SAVE.

It does not send any e-mail automatically. It sends it if I manually run the flow or test the flow. But it doesn't send any emails by itself.

After I click save, it prompts me with this message, next to +New step;
**Ready to create your flow?**
[image]

When you are done adding steps, make sure your flow has a name and choose "create flow". I'm not sure if this message just does not make sense to me or it doesn't make sense at all. Where do I name my flow? I see only that I can rename the different steps which then change the name of the flow. And why would I create flow again at this point? Any relevance?

Another thing that is happening is that when I go in to edit the flow, the timezone and start time have always disappeared and I have to add these again.

Comment: It seems like that it works if i don't give any timezone or any start date&time. But that's not a good enough solution.